# Get html color code for color saved in `Color.xml` in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

All the methods from `android.graphics.Color` seem to return ints and not strings. Is there a way to return the string that represents the Html code for a color saved in `colors.xml` in Android?

Comment: You could convert int value to hex string by calling Integer.toHexString

Comment: int to hex conversion ?

Comment: @DanielNugent it has the int representation of a color. He wants to know the hex (*String that represents the Html code for a color saved in colors.xml*)

Comment: @Blackbelt looks like you're right, looks good!

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
String colour = Integer.parseInt(int);
```